# Log10 function on a range - type 13 mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch, mismatch

I am trying to use the LinEst function to take values from a range of rows of data and input them into a new sheet under some headings. I only want to do this for a particular number of rows (up to row number defined as "c". My VBA skills are very basic, and I have had help producing the code below.

The issue is that I want to transform a range of data (xrng and yrng) by taking log to the base 10 of it. But when I try to use the Log10 or WorksheetFunction.Log10 function, it specifies that the data must be a double and I get a type mistmatch error if I run the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button7_Click()

    Dim xrng As Range, yrng As Range, lxrng As Range, lyrng As Range
    Dim Drop As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant                          ' LinEst result array
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long
    Dim l As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim DownSweep As Chart, UpSweep As Chart, cht As Chart
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Smallest As Variant
    Dim dsws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Template")
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Down Sweep Power Law"
    Set dsws = Worksheets("Down Sweep Power Law")
    Set Rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("B11"), ws.Range("B11").End(xlDown))

    Smallest = WorksheetFunction.Small(Rng, 1)
    l = Rng.Find(what:=Smallest, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    k = Rng.Rows.Count
    c = l - 10
    R = 1

    Set xrng = ws.Range("C11:CP11")
    Set yrng = ws.Range("C201:CP201")
    Set Drop = dsws.Range("C2:CP2").Offset(0, -2)

    dsws.Range("A1").Value = "(n-1) Value"
    dsws.Range("B1").Value = "log(k) Value"
    dsws.Range("C1").Value = "n Value"
    dsws.Range("D1").Value = "k Value"
    dsws.Range("E1").Value = "R Value"

    Do While R < c
        Arr = Application.LogEst(Log10(yrng), Log10(xrng), True, False)
        Drop.Value = Arr    ' or perhaps: = Application.Transpose(Arr)
        Set xrng = xrng.Offset(1, 0)
        Set yrng = yrng.Offset(1, 0)
        Set Drop = Drop.Offset(1, 0)
        R = R + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to learn to use F1.  In the VBA IDE place the cursor on Log10 (of WorksheetFunction.Log10) and press F1.  This opens the MS Help page for the Log10 function (and works for any VBA/Office keyword).  Look at the section of text that describes the input the Log10 function Takes.  Then you will understand why you are seeing the error.

Comment: 'Log10()` requires a `Double` not a range... What would you want to be used by the function? I cannot deduce that only looking to your code... Can you better explain that (in words)?

Comment: `Arr = Application.LogEst(Log10(yrng), Log10(xrng), True, False)` For this line I would want the x and y inputs to be ranges but want to take log to the base 10 of each and every value of the range.

Comment: Then, you must iterate between each cell of the both ranges. I cannot show you here, because you will not understand anything... I will try an answer only for this part.

Comment: You might be able to get away with `Arr = ws.Evaluate("LogEst(Log10(" & yrng.address & "), Log10(" & xrng.Address & "), TRUE, FALSE)")`

Comment: This worked! fantastic! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code, please. Not tested from obvious reasons. I must confess that I couldn't understand where the Drop`range must exist. Its row must be updated for each cell iteration. Looking to the`LogEst` function definition, it receives a range like argument. Not Log10 which cannot be applied to a range... If you need the logarithmic value of each range cell, a preliminary range processing must be done.

```
Sub testLog10()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, dsws As Worksheet, Arr As Variant, Drop As Range
  Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
  dsws = Worksheets("Your sheet") ' use here your sheet name
        Arr = Application.LogEst(ws.Range(ws.Cells(11, 3), ws.Cells(11, 94)), _
                                ws.Range(ws.Cells(201, 3), ws.Cells(201, 94)), True, False)
      Set Drop = dsws.Range("A2")
      Drop.Resize(1, UBound(Arr)).value = Arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I have been using it for other macros now.

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED**

replace:

```
Arr = Application.LogEst(Log10(yrng), Log10(xrng), True, False)
```

with:

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
   Arr = .LogEst(.Log10(yrng), .Log10(xrng), True, False)
End With
```

*(other changes may be required.)*

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am still getting the mismatch error. Is there any way of taking Log10 of each and every value in a range?

Comment: @Judoo123  I just noticed that you are not passing a single value to the `LOG10()` function.  You will need some kind of loop to process **each element** of `yrng` and `xrng`.